# property in subclass of DatabaseConfiguration can not be found in Dropwizard yaml (hierarchical issue)

Tags: java, json, yaml, dropwizard

I want to know. Can i do this or a derivation of it? In my Dropwizard config.yml I wanted to extend databaseConfiguration class so to add another property to the config.yml as below

config.yml

```
database
  driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver
  user: user1
  password: password
  exampleProperty: property1 (Tried a few other permutations)
```

Assume theres a DatabaseConfiguration class that has fields with getters and annotations for driverClass, user, password etc

```
public class AppConfiguration extends Configuration {
  @Valid
  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty
  private DatabaseConfiguration database = new DatabaseConfiguration();

  public DatabaseConfiguration getDatabaseConfiguration() {
    return database;
  }

  @Valid
  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty
  private ExtendedDatabaseConfiguration extDatabase;
  public ExtendedDatabaseConfiguration getExtendedDatabaseConfiguration() {
     return extDatabase;
  }

  public class ExtendedDatabaseConfiguration extends DatabaseConfiguration {
  @Valid
  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty
  private String exampleProperty;
  public String getExampleProperty() { return exampleProperty; };
  }
```

The main class Server.java passes the ExtendedDatabaseConfiguration to the Hibernate Bundle via the call (formerly passed the DatabaseConfiguration)

```
    private final CustomHibernateBundle<AppConfiguration> hibernateBundle = new CustomHibernateBundle<AppConfiguration>() {
    @Override
    //Giving the subclass holding the new database property to the CustomHibernateBundle
    public DatabaseConfiguration getDatabaseConfiguration(AppConfiguration configuration) {
        return configuration.getExtendedDatabaseConfiguration();
    }
};
    SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
    simpleModule.addAbstractTypeMapping(DatabaseConfiguration.class, ExtendedDatabaseConfiguration.class);
    bootstrap.getObjectMapperFactory().registerModule(simpleModule);
```

This is all in order for CustomHibernateBundle to then use this field as it pleases.

Whatever i tried either i got the error jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException or i get the following

```
Exception in thread "main" com.yammer.dropwizard.config.ConfigurationException: powaaim.yml has the     following errors:
* extDatabase may not be null (was null)
* exampleProperty may not be null (was null)
```

Just to note. I have no access to modify DatabaseConfiguration but i can extend it. Wondering whether this can be achieved so that i can define more database configuration properties via this methodology.

Or is there just a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to extend DatabaseConfiguration - I think you just added an extra configuration field that the parser is now expecting (although I'm not sure where the warning about the missing `key` is coming from). Try the following configuration class:

```java
public class AppConfiguration extends Configuration {
  @Valid
  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty
  private ExtendedDatabaseConfiguration database = new ExtendedDatabaseConfiguration();

  public ExtendedDatabaseConfiguration getDatabaseConfiguration() {
    return database;
  }

  static class ExtendedDatabaseConfiguration extends DatabaseConfiguration {
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty
    private String exampleProperty;
    public String getExampleProperty() { return exampleProperty; };
  }
}
```

Comment: apologies @condit. was supposed to fully swap out 'key' for 'exampleProperty'. Amended the OP.

Comment: is there any reason in particular why ExtendedDatabaseConfiguration has to be static?

Comment: I would make it static unless it needs access to its parent class. You could also move it to a separate class if it ends up having many custom fields...

Comment: Fantastic @condit. That was spot on. Thank you.